# html form submit with symbol

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a problem on my website. I want to make a search button with the symbol from fontawesome (`<i class="fas fa-search"></i>`) but I don't know how to replace the form submit with this symbol to submit the form.

```html
<form id="searchForm">
  <div class="search-box">
    <input class="search-txt" type="text" name=""
        placeholder="Type to search" id="inputBox">
    <div class="search-btn">
      <input type="submit" value="Search">
      <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

With this code it will show the Submit button and the symbol.

I hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace input submit type with button.

```
<button type="submit">
   <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
</button>
```

Tweak the button styles to match your design.

Answer (score 1):

you will want to use a button with the `type` of `submit`:

```
<button type="submit" value="Search">
  <i class="fas fa-search"></i> 
</button>
```

With the `type` attribute set to `submit`, it will behave the same as an `input` `type="submit"`.

Answer (score -1):

Helps this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Font Awesome Icons</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<form id="searchForm">
  <div class="search-box">
    <input class="search-txt" type="text" name="" placeholder="Type to search" id="inputBox">
    <div class="search-btn">
      <button onclick="this.form.submit()"><i class="fa fa-align-center fa-save"> Submit</i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```